# Visual Composer 4.9.1 -- Wordpress 4.7.2 после обновления не работает?

Tags: wordpress, wp-plugin, visual-composer

После обновления не работает Visual Composer

не приходилось иметь дело, с платными темами, 
тут стоит тема Kalium, 
плагин тут Envato Toolkit 
есть там пользователь и установлен ключ 
насчет Visual Composer в плагинах нет ссылки обновить поэтому я подумал что это последняя версия
на сайте wpbakery вроде пишут что нужно зайти на свой аккаунт в CodeCanyon 
можно скачать версию
по инструкции нужно удалить эту версию и закачать другую, допустим
а как насчёт страниц которые сделаны на Visual Composer, они как останутся или как?

Comment: А в чем проблема сейчас? Что значит - не работает Visual Composer? Не отображаются страницы, сайт висит, еще что-то?

Comment: просто не открывается вкладка Visual Composer что бы редактировать страницу

Comment: это странно, так быть не должно, похоже на ошибки скриптов. А что в консоли браузера?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $template.get is not a function
    at n.html2element (composer-view.js:145)
    at n.render (composer-view.js:156)
    at n.appendShortcode (composer-view.js:532)
    at n.<anonymous> (composer-view.js:473)
    at load-scripts.php:384
    at Function.m.each.m.forEach (load-scripts.php:384)
    at n.addChild (composer-view.js:472)
    at n.addAll (composer-view.js:466)
    at _ (load-scripts.php:390)
    at m (load-scripts.php:390)

Answer (score 0):

Можете смело обновлять Visual Composer До последней версии - 5.0.1. Со страницами все будет в порядке.

Comment: Обоснуете свой ответ?

Comment: @Kromster Да кроме как практикой аналогичного обновления, обосновать особо нечем. Неоднократно поднимал версию композера до 5.0, 5.3, 5.5 - со страницами проблем нет.